# File inventories and logrotation

Tags: shell, files, logrotate

I want to collect a huge amount of data files on my actual netapp storage with the command `file - f /path... > logfile.txt`.

Through the huge data amount, the size of the logfile will be critical. So I want the use a command/option like logrotate, to split every logfile to a filesize, e.g. 5MB.

Can anybody help me to fix my script?

Comment: Apache's rotatelogs can also be used. Though in a quick test, if the data is piped to it very quickly, you will potentially end up with a file that is bigger than specified.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need

```
| split --line-bytes=... --suffix-length=3 - logfile.txt.
```

instead of

```
> logfile.txt
```